# array_intersect throws errors when arrays have sub-arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

I'm trying to use `array_intersect` to compare two arrays of arrays.

```
$start[]=array(
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'Up',
        'action'=>'up'
);
$start[]=array(
        'id'=>3,
        'name'=>'Down',
        'action'=>'down'
);
$start[]=array(
        'id'=>5,
        'name'=>'Left',
        'action'=>'left'
);




$end[]=array(
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'Up',
        'action'=>'up'
);
$end[]=array(
        'id'=>9,
        'name'=>'Up',
        'action'=>'up'
);

$result=array_intersect($start,$end);
```

However, I always get the notice message:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in testfile.php on line *xyz*

And the comparison doesn't actually occur.

What is the best way to compare the two arrays without reinventing the wheel or arriving at something overly complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone else elsewhere suggested array_map and serialize. I ended up coming up with this--which is certainly much easier than nesting and recursion and failing miserably in an attempt to basically rewrite the array_intersect function.

```
echo '<pre>';

$start[]=array(
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'Up',
        'action'=>'up'
);
$start[]=array(
        'id'=>3,
        'name'=>'Down',
        'action'=>'down'
);
$start[]=array(
        'id'=>5,
        'name'=>'Left',
        'action'=>'left'
);
$start[]=array(
        'id'=>2,
        'name'=>'Left',
        'action'=>'left'
);





$end[]=array(
        'name'=>'Up',
        'id'=>1,

        'action'=>'up'
);
$end[]=array(
        'id'=>8,
        'name'=>'Right',
        'action'=>'Right'
);




function serialize_array_values($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        sort($val);
        $arr[$key]=serialize($val);
    }

    return $arr;
}




$result = array_map("unserialize", array_intersect(serialize_array_values($start),serialize_array_values($end)));

echo "\n\n\n";
echo var_dump($result);


echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: this breaks my original array

Answer (score 6):

The array_diff and array_intersect convert each element in the primary array in to a string for comparison. If you would like a different comparison, then you could use the callback method with the following built-in functions:

```
array_uintersect_assoc() - Computes the intersection of arrays with additional index check, compares data by a callback function
array_intersect_uassoc() - Computes the intersection of arrays with additional index check, compares indexes by a callback function
array_uintersect_uassoc() - Computes the intersection of arrays with additional index check, compares data and indexes by a callback functions
```

I found these by searching PHP.net for the function array_diff and followed the related function links. Its a great way to see alternatives for doing something.

Comment: There is no additional index to check against. None of those functions solve the issue by themselves. What would I call back?

Comment: Well, if its **ALWAYS** a two-dimensional array a callback to another array compare function would work. Another, purpose-built function could be written as well. The idea is to let PHP do the iterating and just to write the compare function as dictated by the given situation.

Comment: I don't have an additional index to supply--and I'm not even sure that the index check is supposed to do. What comparison callback function would be appropriate?

Comment: The index checking is just another level of array compare. If its not needed, a callback that always returns "index match" would work. Here is another answer on Stack Overflow that might be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876435/recursive-array-diff

Comment: That's diff, not intersect.

Comment: I would think array_diff would work though I think the result from it may have to be reinterpreted to the format required by a callback's return value.

Comment: That seems like an overly complex approach to what seems to be a fairly simple problem. All that convoluted code just to intersect arrays?

Comment: The issue seems to be recursively intersecting arrays.

Comment: After messing with this for an hour, I still can't get anything to function as intended. This answer is far to vague.

Comment: Agh, I give up. I can't get it to work. I was trying to avoid reinventing the wheel, and here I am ending up trying to rewrite the array_intersect function from scratch.