# Get common values from all index in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this,

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 145
                [variantId] => 179
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 145
                [variantId] => 180
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 147
                [variantId] => 181
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 147
                [variantId] => 182
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 147
                [variantId] => 181
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 147
                [variantId] => 184
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 145
                [variantId] => 178
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 145
                [variantId] => 180
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 147
                [variantId] => 181
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 147
                [variantId] => 185
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [productId] => 147
                [variantId] => 186
            )
    )
)
```

For this input we can see that `[productId] => 147,[variantId] => 181` is common an all index of array.

Im using `foreach` to check this. But my code is working fine for 2 index, but not for more than 2 index.

In `foreach` im taking `0th` index and comparing with other index, but not working.

Here is the code i have used so far.

```
  $first = $name1[0];
    $a = array();
    unset($name1[0]);

    foreach ($name1 as $row) {// foreach main array
        foreach ($first as $row1) {// foreach first index of array array
            foreach ($row as $kkk => $r1) {//foreach index of main array
                // if first array's index's product is is equal to main array index's product id, push values to one array
                if ($row1['productId'] == $r1['productId']) {
                    if (isset($row1['variantId']) && isset($r1['variantId'])) {
                        if ($row1['variantId'] == $r1['variantId']) {
                            $a[] = $r1;
                        }
                    } else {
                         $a[] = $r1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question

Comment: place foreach function in your question which u have tried

Comment: @131, im not able to get common values from  array if array has more that 2 index.

Comment: @dhruvjadia, please check my code.

Comment: Please add the damn array in the codes so we can test on it.....

Comment: not the output but the php codes where you have stored the array

Comment: @131, [check this link](https://eval.in/738132) for code which is working fine for 2 index

Comment: Dude, you have to remove `unset($name1[0])` from your code, that's what is ruining your code

Comment: @131, im taking that values to `$first` array for checking dude.

Comment: To be honest, i still can't see what you want to do. If you just want to access the array you can do it like this `echo $name1[1][0]['productId']`. If you want to access it through a foreach loop, you have to tell me exactly  what output you are expecting, cause i'm a bit slow xd

Comment: @131, i have added answer, check that you might understand what i actually wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

**First method**

Use this, PHP functions are faster than trying to build your own algorithm.

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

**Second Method**

```
$array1 = array("5","26","38","42");

$array2 = array("15","36","38","42");

$final_array = array();

foreach($array1 as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($val,$array2)){
        $final_array[] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Result: Array ( [0] => 38 [1] => 42 )

**for 2d array**

```
function multi_intersect($arr) {
   $return = array();
   foreach ($arr as $a) {
       foreach ($arr as $b) {
           if ($a === $b) continue;
           $return = array_merge($return, array_intersect($a, $b));
       }
   }
   return array_unique($return);
}
```

you should get

```
Array
(
    [0] => 58
)
```

so finally you  use this to get result

```
$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, your answer works fine if array is `1d`, but not `2d` like `productId and `variantId`

Comment: its simple you need to use one more foreach loop. i update my answer kindly check

Comment: can you provide the input so that i can check if `58 is correct.

Comment: Also [check this link](https://eval.in/738132) for code which is working fine for 2 index

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 87
            [1] => 58
            [2] => 85
            [3] => 86
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58
            [1] => 84
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58
        )

)

Comment: here above is the array data

Comment: Merging `call_user_func_array()`  and my answer, i got the desired result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ya, but see if you can make that necessary changes from my answer so that your answer becomes complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` inside a `foreach` loop

```
$my_array = array
(
  '0' => array
    (
        '0' => array
            (
                'productId' => 145,
                'variantId' => 179
            ),
        '1' => array
            (
                'productId' => 145,
                'variantId' => 180
            ),
        '2' => array
            (
                'productId' => 147,
                'variantId' => 181
            ),
        '3' => array
            (
                'productId' => 147,
                'variantId' => 182
            )
    ),
'1' => array
    (
        '0' => array
            (
                'productId' => 147,
                'variantId' => 181
            ),
            '1' => array
            (
                'productId' => 147,
                'variantId' => 184
            )
    ),
'2' => array
    (
        '0' => array
            (
                'productId' => 145,
                'variantId' => 178
            ),
        '1' => array
            (
                'productId' => 145,
                'variantId' => 180
            ),
        '2' => array
            (
                'productId' => 147,
                'variantId' => 181
            ),
        '3' => array
            (
                'productId' => 147,
                'variantId' => 185
            ),
        '4' => array
            (
                'productId' => 147,
                'variantId' => 186
            )
    )
);

$final_array = array();

foreach($my_array as $nested_array){
    foreach($nested_array as $val ){
        $final_array[] = $val;
    }

}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($final_array);
```

Comment: But how would i get comment values form array??

Comment: You can get value from `$val['productId']`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer which i wanted,

```
function serialize_array_values($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        sort($val);
        $arr[$key]=serialize($val);
   }

    return $arr;
}




$result = array_map("unserialize", array_intersect(
serialize_array_values($name1[0]),
serialize_array_values($name1[1]),
serialize_array_values($name1[2])
));
```

https://eval.in/738165, check the working link

Reference : [array_intersect throws errors when arrays have sub-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010180/array-intersect-throws-errors-when-arrays-have-sub-arrays)

Finally here is my working code

```
foreach ($name1 as $kkk => $row) {
    $list[] = $this->serializeArrayValues($row);
}

$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $list);
$a = array_map("unserialize", $intersect);

function serializeArrayValues($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {

        $arr[$key] = serialize($val);
    }

    return $arr;
}
```