# recursive array_diff doesn't find deleted items

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, diff, array-difference

I try to implement a recursive array_diff, but I sill do not find a 100% working function.

I have two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24077
            [a] => 11
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24078
            [a] => 22
        )

)

Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24077
            [a] => 11
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24078
            [a] => 22
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24080
            [a] => 27
        )

)
```

I tested both Function mentioned here: [recursive array_diff()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876435/recursive-array-diff)

I call the functions via:

```
$diff = arrayRecursiveDiff($array1, $array2);
$diff = array_diff_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

I always get an empty array back. There's one element deleted in the first array, so I expect a result that shows me that one element is missing (maybe an array item with empty content?).

If I change the arrays in the function call:

```
$diff = arrayRecursiveDiff($array2, $array1);
$diff = array_diff_recursive($array2, $array1);
```

I'll get the new one [27]... but I need the way described above.

Do you have any ideas? How would you try to find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: So, you want to find out if a element has been deleted?

Comment: correct. The array's above are only a apart of a bigger array

Comment: Why not just count both of the arrays and if one is larger than the other you know a value as been deleted?

Comment: It's quite difficult to explain... I've a huge array with many sub-arrays an some single values and i have to check the difference between them. It works fine if you add new items and all differences on silimar keys in both arrays are found, but i don't get a hint, when an element is deleted.

Comment: But the two arrays are (if no value is deleted), completely identical?

Comment: yes, they use the same keys.

Comment: Would [array_diff_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) not work?

Comment: not in the way i expected.