# Array_diff getting error Array to string conversion php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i want array_diff using this code i am also getting output but same time error occur

"Array to string conversion"

I am using codeigniter, i am getting post value in second array(listingdata) with method $this->input->post(); , but my first array getting some dynamic key and value then  this two array diff give me output but some time getting error.

Please Help me

Any solution always welcome.

```
 if(isset($_POST)){
                foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

                    $arr[$key] = $value; // making array 
                }
            }

            $result = array_diff($arr,$listingdata);
            print_r($result);
            print_r($arr);
            print_r($listingdata);
```

My $arr array

```
Array
(
    [itemTitle] => fdafdas
    [subtitle] => fadsfdas
    [quantity] => 12
    [itemDescription] => fdas
    [hide_ebay_id] => 89
    [ebay_user] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [ebay_category] => 2984
    [e_sub_cat] => 20433
    [e_second_child_sub_cat] => 117027
    [e_third_child_sub_cat] => 
    [ebay_upc] => 31231241341
    [Brand] => Unbranded
    [MPN] => Does_Not_Apply
    [Model] => fsdf
    [Country/Region_of_Manufacture] => Unknown
    [listingType] => FixedPriceItem
    [listingduration] => Days_5
    [buy_it_now_price] => 20.00
    [shippingtype] => Flat
    [fshippingservice] => USPSPriorityFlatRateBox
    [shippingservicecost] => 2.0
    [shippingsac] => 3.0
    [internationalhc] => 
    [paypalemailaddress] => sam@jaff.in
    [dispatchtimemax] => 3
    [location] => CA
    [ebaycountry] => 
    [ebay_paypalemail] => 
    [ReturnsAccepted] => ReturnsAccepted
    [returnswithin] => Days_14
    [refundoption] => MoneyBack
    [shippingcostpaidbyoption] => Seller
    [policydescription] => wqdewvfdgbfdggrbf
)
```

This is my another Array

```
Array
(
    [itemTitle] => fdafdas
    [subTitle] => fadsfdas
    [categoryId] => 117027
    [itemDescription] => fdas
    [listingType] => FixedPriceItem
    [listingDuration] => Days_5
    [startPrice] => 
    [buyItNowPrice] => 20.00
    [quantity] => 12
    [upc] => 31231241341
    [paypalEmailAddress] => sam@jaff.in
    [returnWithin] => Days_14
    [RefundOption] => MoneyBack
    [ShippingCostPaidByOption] => Seller
    [returnsAccepted] => ReturnsAccepted
    [shippingType] => Flat
    [cshippingService] => 
    [fshippingService] => USPSPriorityFlatRateBox
    [dcPostalcode] => 
    [ShippingServiceCost] => 2.0
    [dshippingPackage] => 
    [shippingHandlingcost] => 
    [shippingServiceAdditionalCost] => 3.0
    [currency] => USD
    [country] => 
    [location] => CA
    [dispatchTimeMax] => 3
    [pictureUrl] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://jaftech.in/ashprey/uploads/69.jpg
        )

    [policyDescription] => wqdewvfdgbfdggrbf
    [internationalShipping] => 
    [internationalShippingType] => 
    [internationalShippingServiceCost] => 
    [internationalshippingServiceAdditionalCost] => 
    [cinternationalshippingService] => 
    [finternationalshippingService] => 
    [internationalShipToLocation] => 
    [internationaloriginatingPostalCode] => 
    [internationalshippingHandlingcost] => 
    [ishippingPackage] => PackageThickEnvelope
    [pid] => 89
)
```

Comment: You want to set a value to every key you have in an array. If you want the value to be empty just set it "". Furthermore you want to give a , after every key => value in your array otherwise you will have even more Errors. Try those two steps pls and post again if you still have any errors.

Comment: set $arr = Array();  before if loop

Comment: `array_diff()` can't handle multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is because array_diff compares values after typecasting both compared values to string (see [documentation notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#refsect1-function.array-diff-notes)).

Both of your arrays contain another array (`ebay_user` and second `pictureUrl`).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877494/2078771) for recursive array_diff, which should work in your case.