# How to print ONLY new array values in php

Tags: php

Assume that I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
   (
    [0] => John
    [1] => accountant
    [2] => senior
    [3] => joined on 2018-03-12
    [4] => http://personalblog[dot]com/abc
    [5] => Germany 
)

[1] => Array
   (
    [0] => Marry
    [1] => journalist
    [2] => junior
    [3] => 2019-04-13
    [4] => http://personalblog[dot]com/efd
    [5] => Canada
)
[2] => Array
   (
    [0] => Jim
    [1] => salesman
    [2] => junior
    [3] => 2017-01-18
    [4] => http://personalblog[dot]com/ehs
    [5] => US
)
[3] => Array
   (
    [0] => Clair
    [1] => director assistant
    [2] => senior
    [3] => 2019-08-22
    [4] => http://personalblog[dot]com/khh
    [5] => Singapore
   )
)
```

And I have a table like this:

```
id      name    ...      Date_joined
---------------------------------
1      Jack     ...      2019-07-25
2      Clair    ...      2019-08-22
3      Jim      ...      2017-01-18
```

I do a `foreach loop` to get the `values` of the array above like this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    echo  $value.'<br />';
}
```

Then I retrieve the table's `name column` by using the `SELECT` query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM tabeName";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['name'].'<br />';
}
```

What I would like to get is to compare the one of the array values, * with the names from the table so that I can `print` ONLY the array values which have not been in the table so far, which are *Marry, and John*.

I got stuck at this step, because I have tried the `if` conditional inside the `while loop` like this:

```
if($row['name']!= $value[0]){

    echo $value[0].'<br />';
}else{
    echo 'No new value found';
}
```

but I just got all the names from the table for 3 times instead of the ONLY new array values from the array which have the new names of *Marry*, and *John*, as desired.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877494/845034.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a array only by the names of the array. 
Then while comparing just check with in_array() function. That will solve the issue.

Comment: I'm very new to `php`, so can you share with us the complete piece of code as a new answer so that I can have a complete picture of it, please? Thanks

Comment: The previous answer is correct. I did think as his answer. You can try the previous answer. Thank you.